# Append object values javascript

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I append the customerApplicationAddress values **no, street, barangay, municipality, province** and put it inside the **customerApplication.address**

```
data(){
    return {
        customerApplicationAddress: {
          no: '',
          street: '',
          barangay: '',
          municipality: '',
          province: '',
        },
        customerApplication:{
          name: null,
          address: null
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how can I achieve this? I tried looping and concatenate it but somehow I'm getting an undefined error.

Comment: but it gives the whole object what i want is the concatenation of the no. street. barangay. municipality and province and put it inside the customerApplication.address

Comment: Where is the code where you tried it? We don't typically write full solutions, we fis=x your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to turn an object into an array of key value pairs & then into a string.

You can do this by using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and then [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const data = {
    customerApplicationAddress: {
      no: '1',
      street: 'Big Street',
      barangay: 'some barangay',
      municipality: 'some municipality',
      province: 'some province',
    },
    customerApplication:{
      name: null,
      address: null
    }
}
data.customerApplication.address = Object.keys(data.customerApplicationAddress).map(k =>  data.customerApplicationAddress[k]).join(", ")

console.log(data)
```

Comment: sir values only not together with key

Comment: There is a [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method which directly gives an array of values.

Comment: I get so used to needing to iterate keys that I often forget Object.values() exists.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using **computed properties** for `customApplication`. Your code would look like:

```
Vue.extend({
  data() {
    return {
      customerApplicationAddress: {
        no: '',
        street: '',
        barangay: '',
        municipality: '',
        province: '',
      },
      customerApplication:{
        name: null,
        address: null
      }
    };
  },

  computed: {
    customerApplication() {

      const addr = this.customerApplicationAddress;

      return {
        // Or consider using string interpolation
        address: addr.no + ' ' + addr.street + ' ' + addr.barangay + ' ' + addr.municipality + ' ' + addr.province
      };
    }
  }
});
```

By doing this, your customerApplication object would be automatically updated every time underlying `customerApplicationAddress.*` value changes.